# Get random id from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of ids. Right now it has 125 ids in it. I only pasted a few. I would like to select a random id from it and use it in a query. I was using `rand_array`, but I had a simple array like this: `array(1,2,3);` with this new array I don't know how to grab a random id.

```
array(125) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#21 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
   string(1) "6"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [3]=>
   object(stdClass)#24 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (1) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "9"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
   string(2) "10"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#27 (1) {
["id"]=>
string(2) "11"
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#28 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
   string(2) "12"
  }
    }
```

Comment: Have you **RTM** ? [`array_rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: try `$rand = rand(0,count($array));` and then `$array[$rand];`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Sure, `array_rand()` is the function to use here, but it will not work by default. The OP has an array of objects.

Comment: @AmalMurali, I know that. I was expecting OP's attempts.

Comment: The OP already states in the question that he tried it using `rand_array` and that it worked with a smaller array like `array(1,2,3);`. He probably meant `array_rand()` instead. ;)

Comment: `$array[array_rand($array)]->id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@Jack* [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980459/get-random-id-from-array#comment35093229_22980459) under the question, this is probably the easiest way to do what you're trying to do:

```
echo $array[array_rand($array)]->id;
```

If you want the IDs for a different purpose, you could extract the IDs from the objects in the array and apply [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) on that array:

```
$idsArr = array(); // Initialize an empty array

foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $idsArr[] = $obj->id; // Push each ID into the array
}

$random_id = $array[array_rand($idsArr)]; // Get a random ID from the array
```

Comment: didn t use the exact code, but it led me on the right track. I ll post my working code later.

Answer (score 0):

Your new array is two dimensional - you need to specify both ID's to grab an element. So try:

```
$rand = rand(0,count($array));
$item=$my_array[$rand]['id'];
```

However I couldn't understand the structure of your array so if you print_r it I can refine this

cheers

Comment: It's not _two-dimensional_ array. It's _array of objects_